# Unable to test should belong_to, missing id foreign key on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

Hello I have been looking for a way to test model relationship and stumble upon 
[should gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda)

- shoulda (3.5.0)
- shoulda-context (1.2.1)
- shoulda-matchers (2.8.0)

Unfortunatly I tried to test a simple example with rspec

```
describe Region do
  it  "should have a city" do 
    should belong_to(:city)
  end
end
```

and I always get a message of

```
Region should have a city
     Failure/Error: should belong_to(:city)
       Expected Region to have a belongs_to association called city (Region does not have a city_id foreign key.)
     # ./spec/models/region_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I though that there was something wrong with my relationships but I have test to create a Region with a city tied to it on `rails console` successfully. I must be missing something!!

**Edit Models and migration**

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :city
end


class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :presence => true
    has_many :regions
end
```

And I created the city after the region so had to modify the migration file a bit:

```
class CreateCities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :longitude
      t.float :latitude
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_reference :regions, :city, index: true, foreign_key: true

  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "cities", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "regions", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "city_id"
  end

  add_index "regions", ["city_id"], name: "index_regions_on_city_id"
```

Comment: You need to post your `Region` and `City` models and the relevant part of your `schema.rb` so that we can assess your data is set up correctly.

Comment: Again please post your schema.rb for Region and City, not your migration of City.  Finally please provide what version of Rails and Shoulda you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Region does not have a city_id foreign key.
```

Your error message clearly points out the problem. 
As, `Region` **belongs_to** a `City`, it's expecting a `city_id` foreign_key in `Region` Model.

Add a `city_id` column in your `Region` model by a migration and then this test will work! 
I think, nothing is wrong here with the `shoulda` gem. It's just your current model setup.

Comment: yes it does seem pretty clear but I still need to figure out why since I am able to link a Region to a city, checked schema.rb and database and I can see a `city_id integer` field,

Comment: do you really need `add_reference :regions, :city, index: true, foreign_key: true` to add your foreign key? It could be an issue. There could be gem version compatibility issue. I could not find anything on that though. still trying. In the mean time, try removing that line, just keep `city_id` column in `regions` table and the proper association which you already have. Then try. Let me know!

Comment: One thing just came into my mind. did you run: `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`? It could be your test database that does not have the `city_id` in `regions` table. Please test this and let me know! Try: `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails c` then try to create a `Region` with a `city` tied to it on rails console (pointing to test database). Let me know about it.